# Android tracking other apps installs

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

With Google Analytics via my Broadcast Receiver I can track MY app installs.

But if there is a way to receive this broadcast when OTHER apps was installed via MY app? For exemple, in my app I can provide to user a link to download third-party app on the google play. Can I receive a callback if this app was really installed ?

Comment: You can listen for `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` broadcasts.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you, but I suppose with ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED I will be notified about all installations, not about only those installed via a link provided by my app? Say me if I'm wrong

Comment: "with ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED I will be notified about all installations, not about only those installed via a link provided by my app?" -- correct. Of course, you are welcome to control the period of time in which you are listening for this broadcast, and stop listening when you believe that it is unlikely that the user is going to install the app anymore.